# Unable to pass state in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-class-based-component

[image]

I'm having issue on the line 24. If I try to declare "query" the same way as on the line 13, warning disappears, but later when I call the function it passes "underfined" there.

[image]

Comment: Why aren't you using `this.state.query`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use query from state like this

```
${this.state.query}
```